# Safari: Canvas elements with a blur filter and clip-path incorrectly show blurred edges

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I've researched similar issues on stackoverflow regarding issues with edges and the blur filter - but this is specifically around the canvas element, and I can't find a solution.

If I have a canvas element within a container with clip-path and blur the canvas element inside, the edges of the element will still be blurred in Safari. The expected result is how Chrome handles this, which is to have sharp edges since it is masked with clip-path.

I've also tried wrapping the canvas element in another div and applying the blur filter to that wrapper, but this also produces the issue. If I use an img element, instead of the canvas element, Safari will render with sharp edges as expected.

Here is a simple codepen to explain the issue. Please compare the result in Safari (16.5.2 in my case) and Chrome to see the difference.

https://codepen.io/Johnny-Slack-the-bold/pen/RwvrRmq

The CSS:

```
.webgl-container {
  clip-path: inset(100px 100px);
}

canvas {
  filter: blur(30px);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can repro on Safari TP Release 181 (Safari 17.4, WebKit 19618.1.3.1) on macOS Sonoma 14.0 I just opened an issue at https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=263862

However I couldn't find a suitable workaround... apart from drawing your WebGL content back on a 2D context at every frame:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xff0000);
const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = innerWidth;
canvas.height = innerHeight;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
document.body.querySelector('.webgl-container').appendChild(canvas);

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
const cube = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( cube );

camera.position.z = 3;

function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
  
    cube.rotation.x += 0.01;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.01;

    renderer.render( scene, camera );
  ctx.drawImage(renderer.domElement, 0, 0);
}

animate();
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.webgl-container {
  clip-path: inset(100px 100px);
}

canvas {
  filter: blur(30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r128/three.min.js"></script>
<div class="webgl-container">  
</div>
```